# Custom Weighs on Errors while Training

Tags: regression, neural-networks, boosting, loss-functions, train

I have a linear regression model, a XGBoost model, and a MLP model that I've developed for a dataset that predicts a binary match outcome using sckit.

I want to set a rule on my model where certain data row entries that I've flagged have a heavier effect towards my model improvement, according to a weighing processes during the training processes. Meaning when my model guesses the outcome incorrectly for certain flagged matches while training, this is factored more heavily then guessing incorrect on regular matches in improving the model.

Is this a possible feature I can input? Would the technique differ across the 3 classifiers, if the weighing technique remains the same?